# convert data frame with character column to data frame with integer column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that shows :

"dataframe1" :

rows : index

columns:

column 1: a gene name

column 2: mutation

column 3: a sample

visually like this:

|  | gene name | mutation | sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gene1 | a | sample1 |
| 2 | gene2 | b | sample2 |
| 3 | gene4 | a | sample3 |
| 4 | gene4 | c | sample2 |

What I would like to achieve is below structure:

"dataframe2":

rows: a gene name

columns:

sample 1: if a mutation occurred for sample1,then put the number1; Otherwise put the number zero.

sample 2: if a mutation occurred for sample2,then put the number1; Otherwise put the number zero.

sample 3: if a mutation occurred for sample3,then put the number1; Otherwise put the number zero. . . .

visually like this:

|  | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| gene2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| gene4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |

How can I convert "dataframe1" to "dataframe2" ? could you guide me please ?

I'm quit new in R . could you guide me please?

Comment: this is called converting data to wide-form, You can look at the function `pivot_wider` from tidyr package. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

Answer (score 0):

As @adroMine said, the best option is pivot_wider from tidyr package.I suggest that you install tidyverse. One solution to your problem is the next one:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Assuming your original dataframe is named "dataframe1"
# Let's say it looks like this:
# dataframe1 <- data.frame(gene_name = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3"),
#                          mutation = c("mutation1", "mutation2", "mutation3"),
#                          sample = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"))

# Pivot dataframe1 to convert it to dataframe2
dataframe2 <- dataframe1 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sample, values_from = mutation, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(across(-gene_name, ~ifelse(. != 0, 1, 0)))

# If you want to rename the columns to match the desired structure
colnames(dataframe2)[-1] <- paste0("sample ", colnames(dataframe2)[-1])
```

With this you should have your solution. If you can provide some data examples It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I tried the code that you have suggested but I got this error :                                                                                                                                `Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <double> to <list>`                                                                           
 could you help me to resolve this error please?

Comment: @fatemeh it seems that your column is numeric, you can convert the mutation column first to a character type before using pivot wider. Like so
dataframe1$mutation <- as.character(dataframe1$mutation)

Comment: dear @Jorge A : thanks for your response and help :)    Actually all columns in my data frame are in character class.

Comment: As you said in order to clarify my issue I edit  question box with give an example. I will be grateful if you take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

```
with(df, table(name, sample))
       sample
name    sample1 sample2 sample3
  gene1       1       0       0
  gene2       0       1       0
  gene4       0       1       1
```

---

```
xtabs(~name+sample, df)
       sample
name    sample1 sample2 sample3
  gene1       1       0       0
  gene2       0       1       0
  gene4       0       1       1
```

---

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(cbind(df, value=1), 
      id_cols = name, names_from = sample, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name  sample1 sample2 sample3
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 gene1       1       0       0
2 gene2       0       1       0
3 gene4       0       1       1
```

---

```
mosaic::counts(~sample|name, df)[-1]

   name n_sample1 n_sample2 n_sample3
1 gene1         1        NA        NA
2 gene2        NA         1        NA
3 gene4        NA         1         1
```

Comment: Possible reasons for dv: no description just codes, and most likely this post is a duplicate.